# How to pass a string variable from shell script to python with sys.argv?

Tags: python, shell, argv, sys

I would like to pass a string variable from a Shell Script to my python script and have it stored in `sys.argv[1]`.
Currently, this is my situation:

main.sh

```
TEST="This is a test"
python main.py $TEST
```

main.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     print(sys.argv[1])
```

result:

```
This
```

How do I send `$TEST` so that `sys.argv[1] = "This is a test"`?
I don't want to have to reconstruct the String after sending it.

Comment: What is the output of `print(sys.argv)`?

Comment: @FreddyMcloughlan that will return a list of all the argv and filename. Example: ['main.py', 'This', 'is', 'a', 'test']

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit your **main.sh** to following :

```
TEST="This is a test"
python main.py "${TEST}"
```

Variable needs to expanded inside "" and will be transformed into its
value.

**main.py**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     print(sys.argv[1])
```

**Result**:

```
This is a test
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
python main.py "$TEST"
```